# Hide UIbutton before I jump into other state

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, sprite-kit

UIbutton remove from MenuScene before I jump into GameScene, or when I don't remove, the button is visible in GameScene, but I draw in MenuScene, why is that? What is the best way to create buttons and change the images of button?

The code is:

```
var button: UIButton!
button = UIButton()
            var buttonFrame = self.view!.frame
            button?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)
            let buttonImage = UIImage(named: "PlayButton")
            let buttonClick = UIImage(named: "PlayButton-click")
            button!.setImage(buttonImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button!.setImage(buttonClick, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
            button!.addTarget(self, action: "PlayButtonClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            self.view?.addSubview(button) 

 func PlayButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(size:self.size),transition:  .crossFadeWithDuration(1.2))
    button.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Put button hidden in the completation func of presentScene

Answer (score 0):

Try that in PlayButtonClick Method:

```
sender.hidden = true
```

This should probably do the trick.

Comment: button.hidden = true, or sender.hidden = true, This hide the uibutton , but button is hide very early, before i enter the GameScene state, and i see that..

Answer (score 0):

button.hidden = true, or sender.hidden = true,
This hide the uibutton , but button is hide very early, before i enter the GameScene state, and i see that..